# Extremely slow SQL select query

Tags: mysql, profiling

The following query:

```
SELECT 
  `so`.*,
  IF(
    ISNULL(`ips`.`border`),
    `io`.`cdborder`,
    `ips`.`border`
  ) AS order_status,
  IF(
    ISNULL(`ips`.`status`),
    `io`.`cdstatus`,
    `ips`.`status`
  ) AS order_state,
  `io`.*,
  IF(
    ISNULL(`ips`.`sale`),
    `iol`.`regelstatus`,
    `ips`.`sale`
  ) AS order_line_status 
FROM
  `sales_order` AS `so` 
  INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `soi` 
    ON soi.order_id = so.entity_id 
  LEFT JOIN `import`.`import_orders` AS `io` 
    ON so.atorder_id = io.cdorder 
    AND so.cdadmin = io.cdadmin 
    AND (error_msg IS NULL 
      OR error_msg = "") 
  LEFT JOIN `import`.`import_orderlines` AS `iol` 
    ON iol.cdorder = so.atorder_id 
    AND iol.cdadmin = so.cdadmin 
  LEFT JOIN `import`.`import_purchase_sales` AS `ips` 
    ON so.atorder_id = ips.order 
WHERE (soi.sku IS NULL) 
  OR (
    soi.sku = iol.cdproduct 
    AND (
      soi.atorder_line = iol.nrordrgl
    ) 
    AND (
      iol.atg != soi.qty_shipped 
      OR iol.at != soi.qty_invoiced 
      OR iol.atb != soi.qty_ordered
    )
  ) 
GROUP BY `so`.`atorder_id`,
  `so`.`cdadmin` 
ORDER BY `io`.`modification_date_order` ASC 
LIMIT 200
```

Is taking 4 minutes to execute! How can this be? Explain shows the following:

```
id     select_type     table     type         possible_keys         key         key_len     ref                                         rows     Extra
1      SIMPLE          so        index        PRIMARY               order_id    32          NULL                                        127828   Using temporary; Using filesort
1      SIMPLE          io        eq_ref       PRIMARY,error_msg     PRIMARY     261         livetest3.so.order_id,livetest3.so.cdadmin  1     
1      SIMPLE          soi       ref          IDX_ORDER             IDX_ORDER   4           livetest3.so.entity_id                      2             
1      SIMPLE          iol       ref          cdorder               cdorder     258         livetest3.so.order_id                       6        Using where
1      SIMPLE          ips       ref          sale_order            sale_order  32          livetest3.so.order_id                       3
```

I tried multiple query profiler tools but none show me detailed information about which part of the query is so slow...

The 'so' table only contains 130k rows... Even with a bunch of left joins it should not be this slow... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add a filter on the sales order table?  Maybe you only want orders from a certain time period?

Answer (score 1):

The EXPLAIN gave you all the required information. The `Using temporary; Using filesort` part is the slow part.

Comment: I'm not sure if your WHERE or GROUP is causing this. Try removing one of them and check the query speed.

Comment: it's the WHERE ... removing it drops my query to 0.003s

Comment: Then lcarus is right - you need to add indexes to the sku. You can also see this in the EXPLAIN - there is no "using where" in the line of sku, but here should be.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the primary key is `order_id` but your query can't use it at all. If you create an index on `sku` your query should run faster.

Note that there's room for more improvement but I'd start by creating an index on `sku` and re-run the query again to see how it performs now.

Comment: I tried doing this ... this table had 500,000 records... it's been running for 25 minutes to add the index :/

Comment: And in this 25~30 minutes, its cardinality has only been increased to 25,000.... so it might take me 10 hours to add this index.

Comment: It might be faster to create a second table with the same structure + index and add the entries from the first into the second table. But I'm getting the impression that something's wrong with you mysql server (slow machine or bad config)

Comment: I am also starting to get the impression that OP's machine is very slow. Adding an index to a 500K row table should not take 10 hours as he estimates.

Answer (score 1):

The query has to retrieve all 127828 records from the "so" table, put them into a temporary table, then execute all the IFs for each record, then sort after the fields you grouped by. Depending on the speed of the machine, it's load and especially the amount of available memory this execution time is not unrealistic.

Comment: How can I optimize this query?

Comment: That is difficult to say. Generally, I like to analyze what lead you to write the query the way you did. Having the database structure helps. Knowing if you're open to change the database structure, to add indexes or change sort orders helps as well. Knowing if you are open to split the statement can help. Sometimes, it's faster to select one part as a temporary table, then join and select the second part using that table. Optimization is easier for shorter, less "bloated" queries.

Comment: well it's certainly not the grouping, nor is it the IF statements... removing the WHERE statement will drop by query execution time to 0.003s

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you WANT out of the data, your query has an instance of "soi.sku IS NULL" which would imply a LEFT JOIN to that alias.  You had a normal join indicating you ALWAYS wanted a record match to "soi"  Did you mean to take that to a LEFT JOIN instead?  If you ALWAYS want the "soi", then I would remove the where "soi.sku IS NULL OR" portion of the query.

Other than that, the query itself looks ok, however, I would ensure you explicitly have the following indexes.

```
Table                         Index
Sales_Order                   (atorder_id, ccadmin)
import.import_orderlines      (cdorder, cdadmin)
import.import_orders          (cdorder, cdadmin)
import.import_purchase_sales  (order)
```

Then, change

```
SELECT ...
```

to

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ...
```